# Find which editor is being used by Terminal when `info` is run

Tags: macos, terminal

I have run the command `info bash` in my Terminal and it opened `bash.info` file in the terminal editor.

What type of editor am I seeing here. Is it emacs, vim, something else?

Comment: `info` by default starts in `emacs` mode, which is not the same thing as starting `emacs`. But what is the core problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to find out which editor it is so that I can learn more about how to use that particular editor (like Emacs in this case)

Comment: info is not an editor it is its own reader which happens to support keystrokes that are the same as emacs.

Comment: use :q to quit the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you started not an editor but the program [`info`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_(Unix)). You can press `?` to learn about the key shortcuts available. As `info` is the GNU documentation tool of choice it's probably no surprise that these key shortcuts closely resemble the ones used by `emacs` proper.